# Prove or disapprove: Group of order $135$ must be abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The question is as follows: 
prove or disapprove: every group of order $135$ must be abelian.

I started like this: $G = H \times\ K$ when $H$ is a normal 5-sylow subgroup and $K$ is a normal 3-sylow subgroup (both normal from sylow theory).

$H$ is cyclic and therefor abelian, but what about $K$? if it's cyclic then it proves the statement. if not, I'm not sure how to continue...

I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: So the question reduces to: does there exist a nonabelian group of order $27$?

Comment: See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_27, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279076/classify-groups-of-order-27, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135072/prove-or-disprove-a-group-with-order-p3-is-abelian-if-its-has-a-normal-subgro

Comment: From the linked answers: take $G = \Bbb Z_5 \times H_3(\Bbb Z_3)$, where $H_3(\Bbb Z_3)$ is the [Heisenberg group modulo 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p).

Comment: The title should be "prove or disprove". Or may be "Approve or disapprove".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to exhibit a nonabelian group of order $135$ of the form $C_5 \times K$, where $K$ is a nonabelian group of order $27$.

The set of all matrices of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
with entries in $\mathbb Z_3$ is a nonabelian multiplicative group of order $27$, called the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192101/589.